# How was the Intel 80486 debugged?

Tags: hardware, intel, debugging

How was the Intel 80486 (from 1989) debugged? I'm assuming it was written in some HDL language, like Verilog. However, how was testing and debugging of the CPU carried out?

Were there several steps to this process, such as running it in an emulator at first, then simulating the Verilog code, then testing manufactured prototype CPUs?

What tests were used?

As a bonus question, are there big differences in how this was done in the late 80s to how it is done today?

Comment: Beside being way to broad to be answered in a single question (it asks for the whole development process, as debuging is an integral part to all steps), ti's rather something for EE, as tocpic and answer isn't confined to retrocomputing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Either of those reasons is compelling for me.

Comment: Since when do answers need to be confined to retrocomputing? For example we've got the questions about using floppy disks today, or power connectors.

Comment: I understand and know that debugging is a broad topic, but I was just hoping for a basic description of the process -- at least I'm asking for a specific type of CPU, the 486.

Comment: @Wilson my reason for agreeing with Leo B. wasn't so much exclusionary as simply that the Electrical Engineering StackOverflow is much more likely to provide a compelling answer. So it's a better destination. StackOverflow's close dialogue offers 'belongs on another StackOverflow site' as grounds for 'off topic' so to that extent the term applies. No further connotations intended in my vote!

Comment: @Tommy No, "a better destination" on another site isn't grounds to close a question as off-topic. A question can be on-topic for multiple sites, not just the "best" one. To use the "belongs on another site" close reason it must be off-topic for this site even if the other site doesn't exist. A lot of programming related retrocomputing questions would be on topic here and on Stack Overflow, for example. See "Don't migrate for the sake of migration": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I'm not sure HDLs are used much in the design of modern Intel x86 CPUs. These are largely full-custom integrated circuits with the transistors and interconnects laid out individually.

Comment: @RossRidge alas, StackOverflow disagrees with you. Go to any question. Click 'Close'. Select 'Off topic because...'. Note that one option is 'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network'. Not 'Off topic because it is, oh and also...'. Suggest you take it up on Meta if you disagree with Stack Overflow's policy, or you think the wording they've used doesn't mean what it says. Or else explain how Stack Overflow's text "This question is off topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" is compatible with your argument.

Comment: @Tommy The answer to the Meta question I linked explains how the "belongs on another site" close reason is supposed to be used.  "**Don't migrate for the sake of migration.** We only migrate questions because they are off-topic on the original site. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere, unless the OP requests migration. As a general rule, if someone asks a question here, and it's on-topic here, it should stay here."  Nowhere does it say it should be used because you think it would be "better" somewhere else.

Comment: @RossRidge I did indeed fail fully to parse your original comment. That's my error, and I apologise to you. But suffice to say: this Stack Exchange site has no definition of what is and isn't on-topic — check the help centre. Therefore the only demarcation is by deduction.

Comment: I think it was put on hold incorrectly. The question has relatively simple answer. The i486 architecture did communicate everything over FSB. The debug was done using an interposer, which hooks the entire FSB with all controls, and there was a test hook to freeze processor execution. The tool was called ICE In-Circuit Emulator. The bus was connected to a very wide logic analyzer (I used Tektronix TLA7xx whole frame), under control of application running on another PC, which would provide breakpoints and digging into CPU internals with full decoding and address means. It was very nice an easy.

Comment: ... Unlike today's tools.

Comment: Ok, I take it back. It is too broad, the question seems to include the entire process of chip design-verification-validation.

Comment: While I agree that the question is too broad, I don't believe that it is on topic at electronics, which focuses on current practices, and I've often seen questions about retro technologies receive dismissive responses on the basis that modern components or methods make the problem easier to solve.  The best option is to rephrase the question to be on topic here, perhaps by limiting the scope only to the difference between today's approach and what would have been used during the development of the 80486.

Comment: This isn't necessarily much too broad, for example the validation strategy for the first ARM core was recently published (mostly directed ASM tests, bootstrapped via software modelling if I remember right) - which is very far from today's approach.

Comment: It appears this question has been nominated for re-opening.  I agree with the original concern that there are too many aspects to this question.  Instead of re-opening the question, I recommend creating one or more new questions on the topic which are smaller in scope.